# Nested as_type Casting

Tags: opencl

When I nest OpenCL's `as_type` operators, I get some strange errors.  For example, this line works:

```
 a = as_uint(NAN)&4290772991;
```

But these lines do not work:

```
 a = as_float(as_uint(NAN)&4290772991);

 a = as_uint(as_float(as_uint(NAN)&4290772991));
```

The error reads:

```
invalid reinterpretation: sizes of 'float' and 'long' must match
```

This error message is confusing, because it seems like no `long` is created by this code.  All values here appear to be 32-bits, so it should be possible to reinterpret cast anything.

So why is this error happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C99, undecorated decimal constants are assumed to be signed integers and the compiler will automagically define the constant as the smallest signed integer type which can hold the value  using the progression `int`, then `long int`, then finally `unsigned long int`.

The smallest signed integer type which can hold `4290772991` is a 64 bit signed type (because of the sign bit requirement). Thus, the `as_type` calls you have where the reinterpret type is a 32 bit type fail because of the size mismatch between the  64 bit `long int` the compiler selects for your constant and the target `float` type.

You should be able to get around the problem by changing `4290772991` to `4290772991u`. The suffix will explicitly denote the value as unsigned, and the compiler should select a 32 bit unsigned integer. Alternatively, you could also use `0xFFBFFFFF` - there are different rules for hexadecimal constants and it should be assigned a type from the progression `int`, then `unsigned int`, then `long int`, then finally `unsigned long int`.